# Gap Between Sprites that are Tiled and Scaled

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, layout

I am working on a map application and I have come across an issue with how my tiles are laying while scaling.

Here is a basic look at my structure:

[image]

There is obviously a lot more going on, but you get the idea. Now, I scale the Map App  `Sprite` to zoom in. When that scaling occurs, there is a gap between each tile.

You can see the gap where 4 tiles meet here:

[image]

I am caching everything as a bitmap. For each Layer (which all extend `Bitmap`), I have `smoothing` set to true and `pixelSnapping` set to `PixelSnapping.ALWAYS` (pixel snapping shouldn't help here, but it shouldn't hurt either).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

(For the sake of completeness, the Map app is built entirely using AS3 and it is embedded in a Flex app)

Comment: what container did you put them in in flex?  and how? a little code goes a long way?   :)

Comment: I'm just putting it in a UIComponent so that I can use Sprites in Flex (the maps need to be usable in AS3 applications as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integers for tile x,y locations and calculating those locations correctly is most likely the fix here, unless the images have seams in them!
The code that calculates and sets the x,y locations would be needed to properly pinpoint the issue in the code.

But, also if you are scaling that container sprite, you would want to ensure that you scale so that the width/height of a tile is an integer value.

For example, if you scale your sprite that contains these tiles, the widths/heights of the individual tiles might not always be integers, therefore creating those seams you see.

What you could do in that case is do your scaling by adjusting your width/height values by integer values, taking into account proportions, as opposed to using scaleX and scaleY on your container sprite.

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. My parent container, the one I am scaling, is being rounded to the nearest int, but the tiles within that container are not. To fix it, I would have to individually scale each tile rather than the parent container and ensure they are all rounded as well. That would mean refactoring my Pan/Zoom class to accommodate such a change. Uncool, but it appears I have no choice. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it's difficult to be sure, but it is possibly just a visual artifact due to scaling - eg: a 250px wide bitmap scaled to 155% should be rendered at 387.5px wide but thats impossible so its rendered at 388px wide - with the 0.5px part rendered as 1px at 50% alpha to give 'appearance' of 0.5px.

Ensuring scaled bitmaps widths/heights are always integers may solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a rounding error.

Without code it's hard to know: it would be a great asset to you and us if posted a barebones example of your tiling class. In the process of subtraction you may very well discover your solution.

I'd offer that you should test what happens when you scale and algin four 100x100 bitmap images at various fine grain steps, to detect if it's a Flash rendering issue or a defect in your class.